# Extract Runtime and Time of Completion from Celery Task:

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

After running a celery task, I get the following message piped to stdout:

```
[2015-11-22 21:08:52,158: INFO/MainProcess] Task jobs.tasks.some_task[9c37f17b-dec4-4cb0-ab2b-fb5e997e430a] 
succeeded in 2.9128301960008685s: 0.9731072908536255
```

I would like to programmatically extract the completion time (here: 2015-11-22 21:08:52) and the runtime (2.9128301960008685s) and display these to the user.

How can these values be extracted from the `AsyncResult`?

Broker is RabbitMQ.

Comment: I think you could just record task start and finish time, return them with result together

Answer (score 0):

Use celery task events to get the task runtime and time of completion. For more details about task events, refer this [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#task-events).

```
from celery import Celery
import datetime
taskId_startTime = {}
taskId_addedTime = {}

def my_monitor():
    app = Celery('vwadaptor', broker='redis://workerdb:6379/0',backend='redis://workerdb:6379/0')
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_task_succeeded(event):
        state.event(event)
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])
        print "runtime: ", task.runtime
        print "time of completion: ", datetime.datetime.now() 

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
                'task-succeeded': announce_task_succeeded, 
        })
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)


my_monitor()
```